# Default language is accessible without locale in URL

Tags: multi-site, craft4, language, sites

I have a website with 2 languages. Each language is setup as a different site.
Each site has its own base URL which is defined as follows: `@defaultUrl/en` and `@defaultUrl/fr`.

I have created a new single section which will be the about page with URI `/about`.
This translates to `https://mywebsite.com/en/about`.

The issue I am encountering is that `https://mywebsite.com/about` is also a valid URL.
How can I make sure that this either throws a 404 or redirects to `https://mywebsite.com/en/about`?
I want the locale to always be present in the URL.

Comment: What do you have in your section's URL path settings? It should give you per-site routing, so that /about should not exist.

Comment: In the section settings I see 2 rows. 1 for each site and the URI is `about`.
Should I prefix this with something else?

Comment: Yes! Prefix with each site's locale slug. Then /about should 404.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your section's settings under `Settings > Sections` and find the table that lists your Entry URI Formats - you'll have a row for each site. Prefix each path with the site's locale, and then /about should resolve to a 404.

Comment: When I do this I can only access the page on `mywebsite.com/en/en/about`.
This is because the base URL for the site also contains the locale.
When I remove the locale from the base URL I can't use the homepage at `mywebsite.com/en` anymore.